# How can I remove these white lines and set a different background?

Tags: phpstorm

This is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVCAe.png) from PhpStorm and as you can see there is whitespace between `$pets` and double braces and also in `@foreach` line. I want to remove those backgrounds and I also want to remove the white lines next to and above line numbers.

P.S double whitespace between `$pets` and closing double braces is intentional.

Comment: those backgrounds ? What do you mean ? You want remove white line ? click on del in this white line... where is the problem ? I don't understand all your issue.

Comment: @darkomen take a look at my screenshot again

Comment: Did you just add black explanations to an almost black image? I can see the lines, but can't read text.

Comment: @Nanne Sorry for that . I didnot pay attention to that. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

The line to the left is a code folding outline; you can remove it by disabling 'Show code folding outline' in `Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding`. 
Green background indicates language injection. You can change a color used for it in `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`, Code/Injected Language Fragment